# Convert UTF-8 to/from UCS-2 in C++98

Tags: utf-8, data-conversion, c++98, ucs2

How can I convert an UTF-8 string into an UCS-2 string, and vice-versa, in the environment:

- **C++98**
- **Boost** is allowed, but no other libraries (e.g. no Microsoft or 3d party)

I learned so far:

- I need UCS-2, not UTF-16. So **utf_to_utf()** alone wouldn't work.
- In C++98 **std::codecvt_utf8** is unavailable.
- Also unavailable: std::locale locale("**en_GB.utf8**") (but promising approach ?)

I can't believe that this is so difficult in C++98 ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just wrote my own conversion function now. You can find it on:

https://github.com/RoelofBerg/Utf8Ucs2Converter

First tests worked pretty well. Please review and contribute.

For future readers: Free license, just use it, but please contribute bugfixes, if you find any.

Have fun :)
Roelof Berg